# Java Minecraft Authentication

Tags: java, post, authentication, minecraft

I need to figure out a way to check if minecraft username and password is valid.

I have found this documentation which is telling a lot of things about the minecraft authentication : http://wiki.vg/Authentication

Looks like it needs a JSON HTTP POST Request but I have no idea how to do that :S

I have searched a lot and went through a lot of exemple but none of these works. The best result I had is no result printed in console or a 403 error.

Thanks

Comment: @MrLore Which do you want ? None of those I tried works. I just took example of POST JSON HTTP Request from google, change de the url and  the request string and it never works. I have never player with this before, I have no idea how it works

Answer (score 7):

I figured out how to do it !

```
    private static String MakeJSONRequest(String username, String password){
        JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
        json1.put("name", "Minecraft");
        json1.put("version", 1);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("agent", json1);
        json.put("username", username);
        json.put("password", password);

        return json.toJSONString();
    }

    private static String httpRequest(URL url, String content) throws Exception {
        byte[] contentBytes = content.getBytes("UTF-8");

        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(contentBytes.length));

        OutputStream requestStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        requestStream.write(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.length);
        requestStream.close();

        String response = "";
        BufferedReader responseStream;
        if (((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode() == 200) {
            responseStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        } else {
            responseStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(((HttpURLConnection) connection).getErrorStream(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        response = responseStream.readLine();
        responseStream.close();

        if (((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode() != 200) {
            //Failed to login (Invalid Credentials or whatever)
        }

        return response;
    }
```

How to use it :

```
System.out.println(httpRequest(new URL("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate"), MakeJSONRequest("YourUsername", "YourPassword")));
```

Comment: Always says invalid password and I'm sure I'm using the right account and password. I tried both email and username.