# Minecraft Authentication Server Returns 405

Tags: java, http, authentication, minecraft

I have tried to authenticate a minecraft account for some time now, and I have tried everything I can think of or I found by searching on google.But whatever I try I get all kinds of different errors like 405 or bad request...

Here is my latest try which returns 405 | Method not allowed :

```
public class Main {
static String authServer = "https://authserver.mojang.com";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    auth();
}
//{"agent": { "name": "Minecraft", "version": 1 }, "username": "example", "password": "password"}


static void auth() throws IOException {
     URL url = new URL(authServer);
      HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
      httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");

      OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
      httpCon.getOutputStream());
      System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
      System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());
      out.close();

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're attempting to connect to `https://authserver.mojang.com`.  While that's the site you use to authenticate, it's not the correct page.  You need to use the endpoint for the specific task you want.  For authentication, you want to use the [authenticate endpoint](http://wiki.vg/Authentication#Authenticate): `/authenticate`.

That means that the URL you need to use is `https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate`, not just `https://authserver.mojang.com`.

You also need to set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` for your request to be accepted.

Per [the errors documentation](http://wiki.vg/Authentication#Errors), you would get `Method Not Allowed` only when you use the wrong method, not the wrong target.  I would expect you would instead get `Not Found` in that case, but I haven't fully tested your code as-is so it may actually produce method not allowed.

---

Here's a sample of how to authenticate based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23462449/3991344) by [Jamesst20](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1019332/jamesst20):

```java
private static String authenticateEndpoint = "https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    auth("{\"agent\": { \"name\": \"Minecraft\", \"version\": 1 }, \"username\": \"example\", \"password\": \"password\"}");
}

private static String auth(String data) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(authenticateEndpoint);

    byte[] contentBytes = data.getBytes("UTF-8");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(contentBytes.length));

    OutputStream requestStream = connection.getOutputStream();
    requestStream.write(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.length);
    requestStream.close();

    String response;
    BufferedReader responseStream;
    if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        responseStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    } else {
        responseStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    response = responseStream.readLine();
    responseStream.close();

    if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        return response;
    } else {
        // Failed to log in; response will contain data about why
        System.err.println(response);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :D, i already read the comment (that isnt there anymore..) and changed the endpoint and got bad request/ unsupported media type. i'm going to try your code later.